# (Why) is it required to flash in order to install Google Play on CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, rom-flashing

Is it required to flash in order to install Google Play on CyanogenMod? If so, why? Or is there a method to install Google Play on CyanogenMod without flashing?

In comparison, other app stores such as F-Droid or aptoide can just be installed as APK, so I am wondering.

I am not wondering about why one needs to install CyanogenMod and the google apps separately, I know it is due to licensing issues.

Comment: You may find an answer at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123358/whats-the-difference-between-flashing-gapps-on-system-partition-vs-installing-f . As @Firelord pointed out, there shouldn't be any difference in terms of functionality between a GApps package installed as system and one installed as user.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123358/whats-the-difference-between-flashing-gapps-on-system-partition-vs-installing-f), an answer has already been found. It appears that the only thing that justifies an installation as system app, for the Google Apps, is to make them unable to be uninstalled via the package manager (since you need root privileges to alter the System partition). As Firelord pointed out in the above answer, there appears to be no further difference in terms of functionality.

If you're wondering about why you're asked to flash CyanogenMod and the GApps separately, instead, I can respond that, due to license issues, the developers aren't allowed to include the GApps directly in a CM package.

Comment: A third-party and ordinary app can have multiple apps sharing the same UID. Example: Automate app from Llama. Your answer isn't convincing. Please provide correct and verifiable facts.

Comment: I have no proof for what I claim, since I didn't test the effective functionality of a GApps package installed as user. Since it already seems to be an answer that may address this question, I propose to delete my answer altogether, and point OP to the other question.

Comment: There actually is an important feature only available to system or trusted apps: the ability to install other applications without enabling the "Unknown sources" option. I think Play Services relies on other system-level permissions as well, but I don't know any off the top of my head (/cc @Firelord)

Comment: @eldarerathis I though of that too but then I also wondered why flashing is needed in particular? Why not just put the apk(s) into an appropriate location under /system and reboot the device. Would it not work?

Comment: @Firelord  I think that would also work. If I'm remembering right, that's how many of the Play Store installation guides for the Fire TV Stick explain it, because it has no custom recoveries currently. Flashing is usually just easier, I suppose.

Comment: Please don't mix things from Cyanogen OS with Cyanogenmod. Cyanogen Inc. is in charge of Cyanogen OS the commercial variant of Cyanogenmod, while Cyanogenmod itself is maintained by the community/volunteers.